# How to convert a list to dictionary where some keys are missing their values?

Tags: python, dictionary, try-except

I have a list of objects with their counts associated after a semicolon. Trying to convert this list into a dictionary but some keys will be missing their values once converted. Tried using try/except but not sure how to store the value individually into the dictionary.

Example:

```
t = ['Contact:10', 'Account:20','Campaign:', 'Country:', 'City:']
```

The Campaign and Country objects would have no values when converting. I would like to either pass or assign a `NaN` as the dictionary value.

I tried something like this but with no avail.

```
for objects in t:
    try:
        dictionary = dict(objects.split(":") for objects in t)
    except:
        pass
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do the values need to be converted to int? Can you show your expected result dict. Just to be clear?

Answer (score 10):

You do not really need to try/catch:

```
t = ['Contact:10', 'Account:20','Campaign:', 'Country:', 'City:']
{ a: b for a,b in (i.split(':') for i in t) }
```

this yields:

```
{'Account': '20', 'Campaign': '', 'City': '', 'Contact': '10', 'Country': ''}
```

If you want `None` instead of empty string:

```
{ a: b if b else None for a,b in (i.split(':') for i in t) }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a generator expression with a split of each item and pass the output to the `dict` constructor:

```
dict(i.split(':') for i in t)
```

This returns:

```
{'Contact': '10', 'Account': '20', 'Campaign': '', 'Country': '', 'City': ''}
```

If you would like the assign NaN as a default value you can do it with a dict comprehension instead:

```
{a: b or float('nan') for i in t for a, b in (i.split(':'),)}
```

This returns:

```
{'Contact': '10', 'Account': '20', 'Campaign': nan, 'Country': nan, 'City': nan}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is missing, it will be an empty string

```
>>> 'foo:'.split(':')
['foo', '']
```

So this leads us to

```
data = {}
for pair in t:
    key, value = pair.split(':')
    data[key] = int(value) or float('nan')
```

This could be cleaned up a little with a dictionary comprehension.

```
import string
pairs = map(string.split, t)
data = {key: int(value) or float('nan') for key, value in pairs}
```

You could also decline to put those keys in the dictionary like so

```
data = {}
for pair in t:
    key, value = pair.split(':')
    if value:
        data[key] = int(value) or float('nan')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = ['Contact:10', 'Account:20','Campaign:', 'Country:', 'City:']
d = {}

for obj in t:
    field = obj.split(':') 
    d[field[0]] = field[1] if field[1] else None

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Country': '', 'City': '', 'Campaign': '', 'Account': '20', 'Contact': '10'}
```

Comment: Why `if len(field) >= 1` and not just the falsey check against an empty string?

Comment: Beginner clarity and making a possibly unwarranted assumption about the actual problem.  Revisited and amended; thanks.